# How to specify 3 different custom colors for 3 nodes in D3 force layout on load

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, force-layout

I am using a D3 api to show some nodes in an order ,the nodes are  coming to the page in same color.When i hover on a node then its changing into some other color. but I want a fixed color for a node (different from others) in the time of loading. I am using this api.. please help me...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .node circle {
stroke: white;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
opacity: 1.0;
   }

line {
stroke: black;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
stroke-opacity: 1.0;
 }
 </style>
 <body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    data = {
        nodes : [ {
            size : 10
        }, {
            size : 5
        }, {
            size : 2
        }, {
            size : 3

        } ],
        links : [ {
            source : 0,
            target : 1
        }, {
            source : 0,
            target : 2

        } ]
    }

    var mouseOverFunction = function(d,i) {
        var circle = d3.select(this);
        //$ fill = d3.scale.category20();
        node.transition(500).style("opacity", function(o) {
            return isConnected(o, d) ? 1.0 : 0.2;
        }).style("fill", function(o) {
            if (isConnectedAsTarget(o, d) && isConnectedAsSource(o, d)) {
                fillcolor = 'green';
            } else if (isConnectedAsSource(o, d)) {
                fillcolor = 'red';
            } else if (isConnectedAsTarget(o, d)) {
                fillcolor = 'blue';
            } else if (isEqual(o, d)) {
                fillcolor = "hotpink";
            } else if(isNot(o,d)){

              //here the output will shown when no mouse event is occured


            }
            return fillcolor;
        });

        link
                .transition(500)
                .style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
                    return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : 0.2;
                })
                .transition(500)
                .attr(
                        "marker-end",
                        function(o) {
                            return o.source === d || o.target === d ? "url(#arrowhead)"
                                    : "url()";
                        });

        circle.transition(500).attr("r", function() {
            return 1.4 * node_radius(d)
        });
    }

    var mouseOutFunction = function() {
        var circle = d3.select(this);

        node.transition(500);

        link.transition(500);

        circle.transition(500).attr("r", node_radius);
    }

    function isConnected(a, b) {
        return isConnectedAsTarget(a, b) || isConnectedAsSource(a, b)
                || a.index == b.index;
    }

    function isConnectedAsSource(a, b) {
        return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index];
    }

    function isConnectedAsTarget(a, b) {
        return linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index];
    }

    function isEqual(a, b) {
        return a.index == b.index;
    }

        //here i have trying to make root  node a separate color and the child nodes two separate colors
    function isNot(a,b){

    return d3.scale.category20()(i);
    }


    function tick() {
        link.attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x;
        }).attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
        }).attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
        }).attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
        });

        node.attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });
    }

    function node_radius(d) {
        return Math.pow(40.0 * d.size, 1 / 3);
    }

    var width = 1000;
    var height = 500;

    var nodes = data.nodes
    var links = data.links

    var force = d3.layout.force().nodes(nodes).links(links).charge(-3000)
            .friction(0.6).gravity(0.6).size([ width, height ]).start();

    var linkedByIndex = {};
    links.forEach(function(d) {
        linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = true;
    });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr(
            "height", height);

    var link = svg.selectAll("line")
                .data(links)
                .enter()
                .append("line");

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter()
        .append("g")
        .style("fill", function (d) {
                    return '#1f77b4';
                })  
        .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("cx",function(d) {
                    return d.x;
                })
            .attr("cy",function(d) {
                    return d.y;
                })  
        //.attr("fill",function(d){return color(d.range);})
        .call(force.drag);

    node.append("circle")
                .attr("r", node_radius)
                .on("mouseover", mouseOverFunction)
                .on("mouseout", mouseOutFunction);

    svg.append("marker")
                .attr("id", "arrowhead")
                .attr("refX", 6 + 7) // Controls the shift of the arrow head along the path
        .attr("refY", 2)
                .attr("markerWidth", 6)
                .attr("markerHeight", 4)
                .attr("orient", "auto")
                .append("path")
                .attr("d", "M 0,0 V 4 L6,2 Z");

    link.attr("marker-end", "url()");

    force.on("tick", tick);
</script>
 </body>
```

[image: This is the output I got]

[image: But This is what I want..]

Comment: How do you determine the colour of a node? Is it in the data?

Comment: no, in the data we can only determine the size of the node.i think the color is given in the below mouseOverFunction function.I think the black color will come when no mouseover is occured in this function.I want to color 3 nodes 3 different color onload

Comment: } else {
                    fillcolor = '#000';
                }
                return fillcolor; this is responsible for the black color  code need to change here to make 3 different colors

Comment: You can use one of the [color scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-category20).

Comment: but how i will put 3 colors in 3 nodes

Comment: Something like `.style("fill", function(d,i) { return d3.scale.category20()(i); })`.

Comment: can anyone help me with that??

Comment: How does the code I've posted above not work for you?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff  I have edited with your code but still not working

Comment: have I did something wrong lars why it is not working ?

Comment: .style("fill", function(o,i) {
    if (isConnectedAsTarget(o, d) && isConnectedAsSource(o, d)) {
     fillcolor = 'green';
    } else if (isConnectedAsSource(o, d)) {
     fillcolor = 'red';
    } else if (isConnectedAsTarget(o, d)) {
     fillcolor = 'blue';
    } else if (isEqual(o, d)) {
     fillcolor = "hotpink";
    } else {
     return d3.scale.category20(i); 
    }
    return fillcolor;
   });

Comment: is this is to be made ??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42709/discussion-between-subho-and-lars-kotthoff)

Comment: will you please see that??

Answer (score 1):

I think you are nearly there with your code. On mouseover you should modify the 'fill' css property of your node.

To do so, in d3 you must use:

```
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", node_radius)
    .on("mouseover",mouseOverFunction)
```

as you did. 
In moueOverFunction you have two choices to get properties for a given node:

1) Get the color from a property of the node:

```
function mouseoverFunction(node) {
    if(node.size<10) {
        return 'blue'
    } else {
        return 'red'
    }
}
```

2) Get the color from the position of the node in the data array:

```
function mouseoverFunction(node,index) {
    if(index<2) {
        // Will color the two first nodes blue
        return 'blue'
    } else {
        // All others will be red
        return 'red'
    }
}
```

In the end for your specific problem I would do:

```
function mouseoverFunction(node,index) {
    if(index<3) {
        return ['red','green','blue'][index]
    } else {
        // index should be less than 3
        return 'black'
    }
}
```